# sharepoint 2007 from sql server to oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sharepoint

I installed WSS 2007 on one of our test server to see if sharepoint is worth going forward for our group. The problem is, it installed a version of sql server and we are using oracle. So, I will need to move sharepoint from sql server to oracle. We can't use sql server we have to use oracle.

I have two questions:
 1. sql server to oracle transition for sharepoint
 2. Is there a performance drawback when we move from sql server to oracle with sharepoint.

I tried to look for resources on web but couldn't find much. Any ideas/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible** - SharePoint can only run on SQL Server:

- [Installation Guide for Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=106632)

> The database server must be running
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2005 or Microsoft
>   SQL Server 2000 with the most recent
>   service pack.

- [Enterprise Sharepoint? – Port it to Oracle](http://bigmenoncontent.com/2008/02/27/enterprise-sharepoint-port-it-to-oracle/)

> I have concluded my only real problem
>   with SharePoint is that you can’t run
>   it on Oracle.
>
> If you had shown me SharePoint, not
>   told me it was from Microsoft and said
>   you can use it with Oracle as a back
>   end, I am sure my reaction to it would
>   have been far different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess you are right. I started looking into solr, it looks like a good alternative for document search, the only thing is we will have to build a front end for it.